# Perl remove digits from a binary number

Tags: perl

I want to remove few digits from a `24-bit binary` number and convert it to `18-bit binary` number.

For example:

if Binary number

```
bin24=111100111011111000100111
```

I want to remove bits `23:22`, `15:14` and `7:6` and the output should be

```
bin18=110011111110100111
```

I know I can do this using `substr()` and concatenate. Just wanted to know if I can do this in one line?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$bin18 = join '', unpack('x2 a6 x2 a6 x2 a6', $bin24);
```

Comment: Ah, someone with better pattern recognition +1.

Comment: A little narrative would be nice

Answer (score 1):

```
my $bin18 = reverse join '', (reverse ($bin24 =~ /([01])/g))[0 .. 5, 8 .. 13, 16 ..21];
```

and other variations on the theme.